# discord.py: wait_for times out though it's None

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a command with wait_for and if the command was excecuted the bot should send a message to a specific channel. Now, the bot should wait until a specific reaction was added. But at some messages the bot doesn't react if the specific reaction was added. And I think it times out though I set it to None. 
It is quite possible that several people are using the Command at the same time. I don't know If that's a problem.

Code:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['Buy'])
async def buy(ctx, choice = None):
    if ctx.guild.id == BlackTVServerID:

        channel = bot.get_channel(705836078082424914)
        channeluser = bot.get_channel(705146663135871106)
        userauthor = ctx.message.author
        vcrole1 = get(userauthor.guild.roles, id=703562188224331777)


        guildemojisbtv = bot.get_guild(712671329123303504)
        Evbucks = get(guildemojisbtv.emojis, id=713138458071269551)
        Erotinfo = get(guildemojisbtv.emojis, id=712677573498372097)
        Epositiv = get(guildemojisbtv.emojis, id=712679512873369610)
        Echeck = get(guildemojisbtv.emojis, id=712726333058318417)
        Eladen = get(guildemojisbtv.emojis, id=713168533416181879)
        Eerror = get(guildemojisbtv.emojis, id=713187214586282054)

        messagechannel = ctx.message.channel.id
        if ctx.message.channel.id in [705146663135871106, 707209203755909190]:
            if choice == '1':
                if any(role.id == 703562188224331777 for role in ctx.message.author.roles):
                    with open(r'./buylimit.json', 'r')as f:
                        userslimitbuy = json.load(f)
                    if not f"{userauthor.id}" in userslimitbuy:
                        userslimitbuy[f"{userauthor.id}"] = f'{userauthor}'
                        with open(r'./buylimit.json', 'w') as f:
                            json.dump(userslimitbuy, f, indent=4)

                        embed = discord.Embed(color=farbegruen, description=
                        f'\n{Epositiv} **5.000{Evbucks} eingefordert!** `Geld wird innert 24 Stunden hinzugefügt`')
                        embed.set_author(name=f'{ctx.message.author}', icon_url=f'{ctx.message.author.avatar_url}')
                        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                        try:
                            embedblock = discord.Embed(color=0xe02522,
                                                       description=f'{Erotinfo} Du kannst nur **einmal Casino-Geld pro Shop Öffnung** kaufen!'
                                                                   '\nSomit ist der Command `!buy` nun für dich bis nächste Woche **gesperrt!**')
                            await userauthor.send(embed=embedblock)
                        except discord.Forbidden:
                            pass

                        embed = discord.Embed(color=0xe02522, title='**__Kauf von Casino Geld__**', description=
                        f'**User**: {userauthor.mention}'
                        f'\n_ _'
                        f"\n**Geld**: 5,000"
                        f"\n**Gekauft mit**: <@&703562188224331777>"
                        f"\n**Gekauft im**: <#{messagechannel}>"
                        f"\n"
                        f"\nReagiere mit {Echeck}, falls erledigt!!")
                        embed.set_footer(text=f'Gekauft am ')
                        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

                        mess1 = await channel.send(embed=embed)
                        await mess1.add_reaction(f'{Echeck}')

                        def check(reactionbuy, userbuy):
                            return str(
                                reactionbuy.emoji) == f'{Echeck}' and reactionbuy.message.channel.id == 705836078082424914 and not userbuy.bot and reactionbuy.message.id == mess1.id

                        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check, timeout=None)
                        checkreact = Echeck
                        await mess1.clear_reaction(checkreact)
                        print('registriert')
                        await mess1.edit(
                            embed=discord.Embed(color=farbegruen, title='__**Casino-Geld ausgezahlt**__', description=
                            f'**User**: {userauthor.mention}'
                            f'\n_ _'
                            f"\n**Geld**: 5,000"
                            f"\n**Gekauft mit**: <@&703562188224331777>"
                            f"\n**Gekauft im**: <#{messagechannel}>"
                            f"\n"
                            f"\n**CASINO-GELD AUSGEZAHLT** von {user.mention}"))
                        try:
                            embedgeld = discord.Embed(color=farbegelb,
                                                      description=f'{Eladen} `Dein angefordertes Casino-Geld ist in Bearbeitung...`'
                                                                  f'\nBetrag: **5.000**{Evbucks}')
                            messembedgeld = await userauthor.send(embed=embedgeld)
                            await asyncio.sleep(10)
                            await messembedgeld.edit(embed=discord.Embed(color=farbegruen,
                                                                         description=f'{Epositiv} `Dein angefordertes Casino-Geld wurde auf deine Bank überwiesen!`'
                                                                                     f'\nBetrag: **5.000**{Evbucks}'))
                        except discord.Forbidden:
                            pass

                    else:
                        embedschongekauft = discord.Embed(color=farberot, description=
                                                          f'{Eerror} {userauthor.mention} Du hast heute bereits gekauft!')
                        await ctx.send(embed=embedschongekauft)
```

I didn't notice any error since I was hosting on a VPS during that time.

Comment: Timeout `None` means that it will never time out, hanging the script until the check is satisfied.

Comment: So, if the command was running twice, the check in the second command run won't work?

Comment: No, it means that if you never react, anything below the `wait_for` line will just hang there and not execute. It won't stop anything else, as the function is a coroutine

Comment: Okay. 
Strangely, sometimes the bot doesn't respond after a reaction was added. I think that's only after a certain time.

Comment: Possibly the check is broken, as the `repr` of an emoji object is nowhere near close to its name / png image / unicode code point. You should be checking by ID, only by name if ID is not possible (like specific role names for example)

Comment: So:

`def check(reactionbuy, userbuy):
     return reaction.emoji.id == 123123123123 ...`
?

Comment: Yes, you should try that, or comparing the `name` attributes of the emojis